# Maven Unable to parse configuration of mojo - wrong class

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb, jooq

Maven appears to be attempting to serialize my configuration into the wrong class, and I'm not sure whether the bug is in maven, the generator library, or my own configuration.

I've got the following XML snippet in my plugin configuration: (see [documentation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/code-generation/codegen-matcherstrategy/), trying to work around [this bug](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5268))

```
<generator>
    <strategy>
        <matchers>
            <schemas>
                <schema>
                    <schemaClass>
                        <transform>PASCAL</transform>
                        <expression>SCHEMA_$0</expression>
                    </schemaClass>
                    <schemaIdentifier>
                        <transform>PASCAL</transform>
                        <expression>SCHEMA_$0</expression>
                    </schemaIdentifier>
                </schema>
            </schemas>
        </matchers>
    </strategy>
</generator>
```

and get the following error when I try to build:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.8.1:generate (default) on project my-project: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.8.1:generate for parameter schemaClass: Cannot find 'schemaClass' in class org.jooq.util.jaxb.Schema -> [Help 1]

`org.jooq.util.jaxb.Schema` doesn't have a schemaClass property, but the object inside matchers -> schemas should be of type `org.jooq.util.jaxb.MatchersSchemaType` according to the [schema xsd](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-meta/src/main/resources/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.8.0.xsd) and the generated-code.

What's going on here? Whose responsibility is it to deserialize this class correctly - maven, jooq, or something else?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I think your configuration is correct. This must be Maven doing funny things when deserialising the XML. I'll investigate this issue and provide an answer later. As a workaround, you can always use an external XML configuration and let jOOQ's GenerationTool deserialise this with JAXB, rather than via Maven. One way to achieve this is by using the [maven ant plugin](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-ant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe that I didn't think of this sooner; I got it working with:

```
<generator>
    <strategy>
        <matchers>
            <schemas>
                <matchersSchemaType>
                    <schemaClass>
                        <transform>PASCAL</transform>
                        <expression>SCHEMA_$0</expression>
                    </schemaClass>
                    <schemaIdentifier>
                        <transform>PASCAL</transform>
                        <expression>SCHEMA_$0</expression>
                    </schemaIdentifier>
                </matchersSchemaType>
            </schemas>
        </matchers>
    </strategy>
</generator>
```